# Jackson converting Map<CustomEntity, Integer> to JSON creates toString() from CustomEntity

Tags: java, dictionary, jackson

I have custom Entity that i want to put as Json to my view page

But when i serialize it in map using ObjectMapper from Jackson i receive String created from toString() method

```
@Test
public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Map<ProductEntity, Integer> map = new HashMap<ProductEntity, Integer>();

    ProductEntity prod = new ProductEntity();
    prod.setIdProduct(1);

    map.put(prod, 1);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
}
```

Received: {"com.onlineshop.entity.ProductEntity@2":1}
where "com.onlineshop.entity.ProductEntity@2" is a String, not an object.

So how can i make it to be an Object?

I need exactly Map, not another type of Collection

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: i expect json like {IdProduct:1,name:123} and etc

Comment: You should review the JSON format. And then review how Jackson serializes a `Map` to JSON. Hint: a JSON object is composed of key-value pairs. A Java `Map` is also composed of key-value pairs.

Comment: You should replace key with value - `Map<Integer, ProductEntity>` and everything should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for your answers.
I solved it by creating new DTO which contains :

```
private ProductEntity 
private Integer
```

fields.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to annotate your `ProductEntity` object so Jackson knows how to serialize it or use a Mix In annotation if you are not able to modify the `ProductEntity` class. IIRC there are also global Jackson options you can set that tell it how to handle POJOs.

Since you didn't specify which version of Jackson you're using I can't link to the correct documents but there is a ton of information available on the Jackson sites on how to use annotations and mix ins.